# How to convert UTF-8 text into a wstring used for SFML?

Tags: c++, linux, sfml

Under Linux

I would like to print text in SFML windows from UTF8 encodage, but SFML uses only wstring, I shawn an example with a constant char* but I would like a char*. The code :

```
std::string str(messaging);
std::wstring wsTmp(str.begin(), str.end());
```

nor:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> convert;
std::u16string dest = convert.from_bytes(source);
```

nor:

```
std::vector<char> v(messaging, messaging + strlen(messaging));
std::string str(v.begin(), v.end());
std::wstring wstr(v.begin(), v.end());
```

I tried others code from overflow but it doesn't work, and it is old messages, so maybe there is another function ?

Comment: What other code did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: You can use [`wide_from_utf8` from my *stdlib* pure header library at GitHub](https://github.com/alf-p-steinbach/stdlib/blob/master/source/extension/utf8_conversion.hpp). It's still limited to the BMP of Unicode, though. I haven't had the time to fully support 32-bit `wchar_t`.

Comment: Use `sf::String sfstr = sf::String::fromUtf8(str.begin(), str.end())`

Answer (score 1):

SFML uses it's own string class, `sf::String`.

You can convert from an `std::string` that contains UTF-8 to an `sf::String` by using the static [fromUtf8](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1String.php#aa7beb7ae5b26e63dcbbfa390e27a9e4b) method:

```
std::string str(messaging);
sf::String sfTmp = sf::String::fromUtf8(str.begin(), str.end());
```

You should be able to use `sfTmp` anywhere in SFML you need a string.